# Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error was Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors() in C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\application\views\dtr_timerecord_overtime.php on line 5.

i tried to out the error message to other views and it was ok but when im trying to its original view it always error

**view**

```
<table border="0">

        <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> </td?
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=""><label>OT APPLICATION NO</label></td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtOtApplication" name="txtOtApplication" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"><label>DATE</label></td>
            <td align="right"><input id="labelDateTodayOvertime" disabled/></td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" id='txtDateTodayOvertime' name="txtDateTodayOvertime"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=""><label>DESCRIPTION</label></td>
            <td colspan="5">
            <input type="text" id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription" />
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">
            <td><label>EMPLOYEE</label></td>
            <td><label>DATE</label></td>
            <td><label>TIME FROM</label></td>
            <td><label>TIME TO</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

    <div id="OVERTIME_ADDLINE-div" on>
        <div>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmployee" name="txtEmployee" size="30"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="date" id="txtDate" name="txtDate" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="time" id="txtTimeFrom" name="txtTimeFrom" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            <input type="time" id="txtTimeTo" name="txtTimeTo" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnAddLine" name="btnAddLine" value="ADD LINE" />
            </td>

            </div>
        </div>

        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr align="center">
            <td>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSaves" value="SAVE AND SUBMIT">
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" name="btnReset" value="RESET" onclick='ClearFields();'>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" name="btnGenerate" value="GENERATE">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dtr_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
public function saveovertime(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtOtApplication', 'Overtime Application No.', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtDescription', 'Description', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtEmployee', 'Employee', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtTimeFrom', 'Time From', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtTimeTo', 'Time to', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtDate', 'Date', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('dtr_timerecord_overtime');
        }
        else
        {   
        $this->load->model('dtr_model');
        $this->dtr_model->saveovertime();
        $this->load->view('success_overtime');

        }

    }   
}
```

**model**

```
class Dtr_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

    }

    function saveovertime(){
        $value = array(
                        'OT_APPLICATION_NO'=>$this->input->post('txtOtApplication'),
                        'DESCRIPTION'=>$this->input->post('txtDescription'),
                        'DATETODAY'=>$this->input->post('txtDateTodayOvertime'));

        $query = $this->db->insert('dtr_timerecord_overtime',$value);
        $value = array(
                        'EMPLOYEE'=>$this->input->post('txtEmployee'),
                        'TIME_FROM'=>$this->input->post('txtTimeFrom'),
                        'TIME_TO'=>$this->input->post('txtTimeTo'),
                        'DATE'=>$this->input->post('txtDate')); 
        $query = $this->db->insert('dtr_timerecord_overtime_line',$value);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's my workaround:

First I had this in my View:

```
<?php
    echo validation_errors();
?>
```

It didn't work. I kept receiving **Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors()**...

Then I did this:

```
<?php
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    echo validation_errors();
?>
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded `form_helper` in `application\config\autoload.php`, please load `form` helper in autoload file

Or on the controller

```
$this->load->helper("form");
```

`validation_errors()` function is inside form helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

write this in the constructor of your controller, or better autoload it. perhaps, in the method, you are posting this form, you accidentaly not loading the form validation library

Comment: from which controller you are calling this view?

Comment: dtr_controller / saveovertime $this->load->view('dtr_timerecord_overtime');